# How to install impala on windows

Tags: windows, impala

I wanted to install Impala on Windows. I found on Impala official document that it is only supported on Linux-like operating systems. Is there any way to install Impala on Windows, like build and then install?

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker toolbox to install impala on windows.

```
docker run -t -i lancope/impala-shell
```

Reference: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Can-i-install-impala-shell-in-windows-machine/td-p/30974

Comment: I guess this is only for impala shell. I want to install single node impala on my windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.

Unlike most components in the Hadoop ecosystem that are written in Java, Impala is written in C++ and has an extensive number of libraries and tools that would have to be ported in order to just satisfy the prerequisites for building Impala on Windows.  Then there are the OS differences between Linux and Windows so you'd also have to change the build scripts to work with Windows-style paths and naming conventions plus you'd have to iron out any OS incompatibilities.

All of this, by the way, is to simply **build** Impala on Windows.  Getting Impala to work on Windows might involve even more effort.

Comment: Look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Impala+Build+Prerequisites